# How to select certain rows with an sql statement depending on whats in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Okay so I have a database as such,

**journey_driver**

```
driver_id  j_id
23          1
23          2
1           3
```

**journey_details**

```
j_id  starting_point  end_point  start_time  end_time
1         Dublin        Cork       4:00        7:30
2         Galway        Mayo       16:00       18:00
```

So if I wanted to create a select statement to select and display the journeys that driver #23 has driven on which are #1 and #2. How would I then display the details of those journeys? Which should display.....

```
j_id  starting_point  end_point  start_time  end_time
1         Dublin        Cork       4:00        7:30
2         Galway        Mayo       16:00       18:00
```

I'm using php and have the driver #23 logged in and I have the #driver_id stored in a variable. I know I have to compare in the sql statement. Any help on this would be great its driving me crazy.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Any codes maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Join

```
SELECT jd2.*
FROM journey_driver jd1
LEFT JOIN journey_details jd2
ON jd1.j_id = jd2.j_id
WHERE jd1.driver_id = 23
```

SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7739f4/1

Comment: Thanks a million. Worked a treat.